# Use JSON data for android listview section header

Tags: android, mysql, json, listview

I'm wondering if someone can help me figure out what I'm not getting with trying to use a date from a JSON result as a section header? I'm Using the following list adapter code from http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/

```
package com.example.androidhive;

import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;

public class SeparatedListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

public final Map<String, Adapter> sections = new LinkedHashMap<String, Adapter>();
public final ArrayAdapter<String> headers;
public final static int TYPE_SECTION_HEADER = 0;

public SeparatedListAdapter(Context context) {
    headers = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.list_header);
}

public void addSection(String section, Adapter adapter) {
    this.headers.add(section);
    this.sections.put(section, adapter);
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    for (Object section : this.sections.keySet()) {
        Adapter adapter = sections.get(section);
        int size = adapter.getCount() + 1;

        // check if position inside this section
        if (position == 0)
            return section;
        if (position < size)
            return adapter.getItem(position - 1);

        // otherwise jump into next section
        position -= size;
    }
    return null;
}

public int getCount() {
    // total together all sections, plus one for each section header
    int total = 0;
    for (Adapter adapter : this.sections.values())
        total += adapter.getCount() + 1;
    return total;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    // assume that headers count as one, then total all sections
    int total = 1;
    for (Adapter adapter : this.sections.values())
        total += adapter.getViewTypeCount();
    return total;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    int type = 1;
    for (Object section : this.sections.keySet()) {
        Adapter adapter = sections.get(section);
        int size = adapter.getCount() + 1;

        // check if position inside this section
        if (position == 0)
            return TYPE_SECTION_HEADER;
        if (position < size)
            return type + adapter.getItemViewType(position - 1);

        // otherwise jump into next section
        position -= size;
        type += adapter.getViewTypeCount();
    }
    return -1;
}

public boolean areAllItemsSelectable() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return (getItemViewType(position) != TYPE_SECTION_HEADER);
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    int sectionnum = 0;
    for (Object section : this.sections.keySet()) {
        Adapter adapter = sections.get(section);
        int size = adapter.getCount() + 1;

        // check if position inside this section
        if (position == 0)
            return headers.getView(sectionnum, convertView, parent);
        if (position < size)
            return adapter.getView(position - 1, convertView, parent);

        // otherwise jump into next section
        position -= size;
        sectionnum++;
    }
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
}
```

Along with the PHP/MySQL/Sample code from here: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

I've managed to get a sectioned list somewhat working by using the following:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
    pDialog.dismiss();
    // updating UI from Background Thread
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        /**
        * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
        * */
    SeparatedListAdapter listadapter = new SeparatedListAdapter(
                activity);
        String date = null;
        try {
            JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(1);
            date = c.getString(TAG_DATE);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        listadapter.addSection(date, new SimpleAdapter(activity,
                productsList, R.layout.list_item, new String[] {
                TAG_PID, TAG_NAME, TAG_DATE }, new int[] {
                R.id.pid, R.id.name, R.id.date }));
        listadapter.addSection("Security Test", new SimpleAdapter(
            activity, productsList, R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] { TAG_PID, TAG_NAME, TAG_DATE },
            new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name, R.id.date }));

                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(listadapter);
            }
        });

    }
```

However, that results in something like this:

[image]

Is there a way to parse the date from the JSON query, then use it in a "for" block so that each section would be the date (specifically the month) and then only show the values in each section per that month? I'm using the following to get the Month Name, but this doesn't help filtering the list:

```
SeparatedListAdapter listadapter = new SeparatedListAdapter(
                    activity);
            java.util.Date datestr = null;
            String month_name = null;

            try {

                JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(1);

                SimpleDateFormat inputFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                                "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); 
                SimpleDateFormat outputFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                                "MMMM");

                try {
                    datestr = inputFormatter.parse(c
                            .getString(TAG_DATE));
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                month_name = outputFormatter.format(datestr);
```

Comment: Have a look at implementing a `Filterable` on your `SeparatedListAdapter`.

Comment: thanks for the info, reading up on filterable now.   One solution, though not perfect that I thought about, was using sets and filling them with the values required...for example, lets say i group just by days of the week:

    Monday
     -item 1
     -item 2

   Tuesday
     -item 1
     -item 2

then using each set to fill the section header and then populate the list.  This obviously wouldn't be perfect, but it might work...trying to do the "math" in my head to make it work

Comment: did you find the answer ?

Comment: @gaurang let me check tonight.   I ended up dropping out of development on the app this was for, but let me look in my git repo tonight and get back to you to see if I solved this.