# Custom Header in listview from parsed JSON Array

Tags: android, android-listview, arrays

I am showing JSON data in listview.
I am parsing JSON array and getting 3 values.

1. time , is in format (8/1/2013 12:30:00 PM)
2. place , is in string format
3. address , is in string format

Now I want to show header as those event are on 8/1/2013 are shown under header name as date "8/1/2013" and those entries on different date shown under their respective section with proper date

Piece of my code:

```
ArrayList<RidesValue> alrides = new ArrayList<RidesValue>();
List<String> rides = new ArrayList<String>();
ListView listView;

 public class RidesValue
 {
    String time;
    String place;
    String address;

 }

public void displaylist(String time, String place, String address)
{
    RidesValue rideval = new RidesValue();

    rideval.time = time;
    rideval.place = place;
    rideval.address = address;

    alrides.add(rideval);

    rides.add("Time: " + time + "\nPlace: " + place
            + "\nAddress: " + address);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplelist, rides);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvride);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

I call displaylist method every i parse a single array from json array:

```
                    JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(savedresponse);

            if(jarray.length() == 0)
                Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry no rides found",                                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Log.i("JSON ARRAY",String.valueOf(jarray));

            for(int i=0; i<jarray.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject value = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                time = value.getString("Time");
                place = value.getString("Place");
                address = value.getString("Address");

                displaylist(time, place,address);
            }
```

So question is where and how i put  n what code so group entries by under date as header in list view

Answer (score 0):

Your question was not so clear. But as much I understood i think you can go for Expandable ListView.

Comment: I am parsing JSON array and showing in list view, as told above i am getting time in that format, now i want to group each event which occur in same date under same header , where header content is just date. so question is how i know about expandable list

Comment: just like this    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11940641/use-json-data-for-android-listview-section-header